# git says a binary file is created upon clicking the existing files in my cd

Tags: macos, resource-fork

This is actually not an issue like "Git says my file is modified while it is not". So, I don't think that this may be a line ending issue.
Instead, git says that a new file is created starting with **"._"**.

For example, when I click **myfile.ext** in my directory, `git status` show that a new file is created as **._myfile.ext** in the same directory although it is not seen in my local cd. However, when I push it, it is there in the remote but it cannot be opened.

When I started using git, I didn't have this problem but I am experiencing this recently.
Should I simply `.gitignore` or can we actually see the source of this issue?

[Github Desktop showing a binary file is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWHcC.jpg)

Comment: Git is not a GUI and you can't click files in it. I'm not sure what you're using (perhaps GitHub Desktop), but it's not *Git*.

Comment: let me clarify. It is, when I click the files in my directory, not in the GH Desktop.

Comment: So: what program(s) activate(s) when you click files? It's that program, or those programs, that are doing this.

Comment: It is the same for all programs I use. I might be csv, xlsx, do, m, ... etc. with any extension and any program, i have this issue.

Comment: Hm, so, what OS and desktop-y environment are you using?

Comment: macOS BigSur 11.4.

Comment: OK, that's weird. I have Big Sur installed and I literally *can't* click on files that have `.do` extensions as I get a Finder error saying that there is no app set to open such files. Files that get opened in TextEdit do get extended ACLs set on them (so that the permissions become `rw-r--r--@`). I wonder if these `.-` files are being used to store data for files that aren't in HFS, that would normally go in a resource fork. In any case it's some *app* you've chosen to open these files that's doing it. Find out which app.

Comment: See also https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4947897 (which specifically mentions how these are used as fake resource fork files).

Comment: maybe I should have said myfile.ext. the problem is not with .do in my case. Ok, let me check the link.

Comment: You might also want to read [ask] then: your [mcve] was not a reproducer at all! :-)

Comment: seemingly, it is caused by the external drive I'm using per the comments [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them)

Comment: Yep, this is the same resource fork issue. I'm not too surprised that Apple sticks extended attributes into the resource fork; the methods used on other file system implementations are klunkier. As far as Git itself goes, just add `._*` to your `.gitignore` to make it shut up about them.

Comment: This is what I just did. thanks. I'll be careful with my Q's next time.